# one to many or many to many relationship in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I wanna try to build a relationship between an employee and an area. Each employee has to visit more than one area and the area depends on the city. I built a relationship between city and area with a foreignkey(many-to-one). I have to add more than one areas to single employee however, I used manytomany relationship between employee and area. At the time of employee registration when I select city from "City" dropdown the list of the area is not altered. All the areas are shown.
This is my Employee form

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model =Employee
        fields = ('code','first_name','last_name','designation','report_to','join_date','leave_date','city','area','username','password','status','address')
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.none()

            if 'city' in self.data:
                try:
                    city_id = int(self.data.get('city'))
                    self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(city_id=city_id).order_by('name')
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
            elif self.instance.pk:
                self.fields['area'].queryset = self.instance.city.area_set.order_by('name')
```

and models are

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    # name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    designation =models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    report_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.ManyToManyField(Area, through ='EmployeeArea',)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    join_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    leave_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

if I made wrong relationship then please guid me.

Comment: If you want to alter the second dropdown depending on what you selected in the first one you need to implement a "chained-dropdown". When you select something, you need to fetch the new data via ajax. Read more about in this [post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html).

Comment: @wfehr I would do the same thing if second is the dropdown list too. But in the second list, I have an m2m relationship. Therefore Which is not working with it.